# Passar parâmetros para Modal em jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho o seguinte botão:

```
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-cliente='.$r->idCliente.' data-datainicial='.$_GET['data_inicial'].' data-datafinal='.$_GET['data_final'].' data-target="#myModal">Boleto</button>';
```

Gostaria de recuperar `data-cliente, data-datainicial, data-datafinal` e coloca-la dentro da modal na `div`:

```
<div...>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="teste/cliente/datainicial/datafinal"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Gerar PDF</button></a> <---- Aqui preciso recuperar estas 3 variaveis. 
          <a href="teste/cliente/datainicial/datafinal"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Enviar E-Mail</button></a> <---- Aqui preciso recuperar estas 3 variaveis. 
        </div>
</div>
```

Como posso recuperar estes dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não encontrei uma maneira de saber qual o botão que abriu o `dialog`, mas usando uma variável para passar esse elemento já é possivel. Testa assim:

```
var handler;
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
}).on("dialogopen", function (event, ui) {
    var $btn = $(handler);
    var id = $btn.data('cliente');
    var dataInicial = $btn.data('datainicial');
    var dataFinal = $btn.data('datafinal');
    var buttons = $(event.target).find('.btn').attr({
        'data-cliente': id,
        'data-datainicial': dataInicial,
        'data-datafinal': dataFinal
    });
});;


$('.btn').click(function () {
    handler = this;
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Vou explicar mais logo o códgigo, agora demorei mais do que previa e fiquei com pressa para sair...

Comment: Mas ai como eu recupero as variáveis dentro da modal?

Comment: @AndréBaill depende um pouco do que queres fazer. Se explicares melhor como precisas desses dados posso adaptar. A resposta como está passa o que está nos campos `data-` para novos campos `data-` no HTML onde referiste que precisavas.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui a solução desta forma, caso alguém precise também:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".boleto_campo").click(function(){ 
            $("#cliente").val($(this).data('cliente'));
            $("#datainicial").val($(this).data('datainicial'));
            $("#datafinal").val($(this).data('datafinal'));
            var cliente = $(this).data('cliente');
            var datainicial = $(this).data('datainicial');
            var datafinal = $(this).data('datafinal');
            $("#form_modal").modal('show');

            $(".gerar_pdf").click(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                window.location.href = "<? echo base_url('boleto/gerar/'); ?>/" + cliente + "/" + datainicial + "/" + datafinal;    
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```